# Whats the best practice for git on a live and stage setup?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-post-receive

I was wondering if that is a good version for my live and stage setup.

1 Adminserver with 2 Appservers - Live

1 Adminserver with 1 Appserver - Stage

1 Gitlabserver

4 Developers

We already got the gitlab server and are using it just for tracking all of our changes. Now we want to deploy with the setup. I thought we could create a bare repo on the Adminservers and Appservers and setup a post-receive hook on each of them. The main remote origin would be the Gitlabserver and the other ones would be added as **remote stage** and **remote live**

The post-receive hooks with add the worktree (/var/www/test) and checkout the project and the changes made.

Is this a/the way to go? I could not find such a funcionality in Gitlab - maybe there is?

Comment: where do you place your builds/distribution? do you have testing?

Comment: @legnoban its an PHP App and we are "testing" on our local hosts.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." (from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the docker image repo from gitlab if it fits your need. You can build docker image from the stable source (usually on master branch). Instead of pulling the source code to your stage and live servers, you will pull docker image (which is conceptually your application wrap in the image environment). This is an opinionated answer